# Dock favourites to open with double click

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, doubleclick

The favourites in the dock opened by single click. Is it possible to make it double click?
it is 18.04 LTS.
I pretty often do double click and open 2 instances instead of one, because I feel it rather as a part of desktop where it needs double click.

Comment: Also it's easy to open by accident.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way to do that currently, unfortunately.